# Why am I getting the error "your request is timed out. please retry the request" once in a while?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, shared-hosting

Hi I have recently uploaded my site on a deluxe shared hosting account (GD). Once in a while I get a plane page containing only the text "your request is timed out. please retry the request." I'm unable to figure out the cause. I'm using IE8 for testing. On server side, I have custom MVC like architecture and the errors are being handled globally. Whenever this error appears, it appear instantly when I try post back. Going back and retrying the same solves the issue. No app logging occurs as it doesn't seem to be issue with the code. Does somebody have an idea as to What's wrong here?

Comment: Most likely, either a record dead lock in a database, or, a query taking too long, or just general overloading on the server

Comment: Because some hosting providers (GD) are much like their advertising, Long on implied promises, short on delivery.

Comment: The first two causes seem unlikely in this case as they would raise some sort of exception which my global/other handlers would have logged. The overload point can hold but I'm the only user of the site right now :). Have just recently uploaded it. Is it issue with GD since the account type is shared hosting?

Comment: You're the only user of your web site, but there might be many other users on other sites hosted on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it could be an issue with having PHP enabled on your asp.net hosting package.
http://www.mynetnuke.com/2011/02/your-request-timed-out-please-retry.html

If that's not it, I would try to narrow it down via tracing.

Enable tracing for the page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx

Enable tracing for the application and access it via trace.axd (e.g., http://website.com/trace.axd)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx

Use Elmah to trace / gather more information
http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

If all else fails, contact GoDaddy support.

Comment: Awesome troubleshooting / links!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this thread is your problem.

http://community.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/your-request-timed-out-please-retry-the-request/?topic_page=5&num=15